# Excel - Forumla to seacrh for mutliple terms and show the matching term

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, lookup

I have the challenge that I need to search in Excel for multiple terms and to get the result back for each cell which of the different terms has matched.

I know there is a formula combination to search for multiple terms but this will not give me the matched term back. The exampel below gives only a "0" or "1" back.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"TermA","TermB","TermC"},A1)),"1","0")
```

```
|   |         A       |     B   |
| 1 | This is TermA   |  TermA  |
| 2 | Some TermB Text |  TermB  |
| 3 | And TermA Text  |  TermA  |
| 4 | another TermC   |  TermC  |
```

Background I have to do some normalization of the values and look therefore for some forumla which can identify the values and list the match. The values which are  used to search for should be later on another page so it can be easily extended.

Thank you for some hints and approaches which will put me into the right direction.

Comment: In your last example "TermC" is part of a longer substring "TermCt". Is this on purpose, i.o.w. is it possible for the term to be part of another word?

Comment: good spotted. Well to simplify it can be just the exact term "TermC" so I will update the example to avoid confusion and to focus on the core problem

Comment: Another question, does always one term exist *and* can there ever be two terms exist in a single value?

Comment: I am happy with the return of the first match, so this should be then more simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return all matching terms:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.='TermA' or .='TermB' or .='TermC']"),COLUMN(A1))
```

[image]

Wrap in an `IFERROR()` if no match is found at all.

---

If one has ExcelO365 and you refer to a range, things got a lot easier:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(C$1:C$3,ISNUMBER(FIND(C$1:C$3,A1))))
```

Comment: You are a hero,. Do you see a possibility to use instead  `[.='TermA' or .='TermB' or .='TermC']`an excel range?

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? @megloff. If you have a lookup-table, things could drastically become easier =)

Comment: Excel 365 - Yes the idea is to use a lookup table which contains all the terms  for which I like to search for

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising, I will test it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX(FILTER(C:C,C:C<>""),MATCH(1, COUNTIF(A1, "*"&FILTER(C:C,C:C<>"")&"*"), 0))`

For use in office 365 version. If previous version replace `FILTER(C:C,C:C<>"")` with `C$1:C$4` for your example or whatever your range of search values may be. Table reference is also possible.

The formula searches for the first match in your list of values if the text including your term contains a matching value anywhere in that text. It returns the first match.